# Slowing down music in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, background-music

I'm developing a game using as3 in FlashDevelop.

In my game my character is a ninja that can enter to a focus mode where the game enters slow-motion.

The slow-motion is not a problem.

(I'm doing
    stage.frameRate /= 2;
and after some time
    stage.frameRate *= 2;
)

But in my game the music is tuned to the progress so I want to slow down the music as well - is that possible?

I can use 2 files of music where the second is already slowed down, but that will make my game 3 times heavier.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract%28%29

Comment: i was hoping for a little more details..  i can extract byte array of data. now what? what is the bytes per second ratio? how can i play the byteArray?

Comment: There is a full blown example there that shows how to up the octave. Start there

Comment: can i just copy each byte from the source byteArray two times to the target byteArray ? does it make sense?

Comment: where i can find information about how manipulating the data will change the music.. i see in the example that they discard every other float data which cause an octave up..